# Retrieving Azure Service Bus messages from Topic using a filtered subscription

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to follow Mark Heath's console application [example](https://markheath.net/post/filtered-azure-service-bus-subscriptions) to retrieve Service Bus topic messages using a filtered subscription.  However, I'm not actually able to retrieve the actual filtered messages (Filtered1, Filtered2).  The messages do get consumed but I'm not able to view them because the code never makes it into the callback function like it does with non filtered messages (AllMessages).  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Sender Code

```
var body = "Hello World";
var message1 = new BrokeredMessage(body);
message1.Properties["From"] = "Ian Wright";

var message2 = new BrokeredMessage("Second message");
message2.Properties["From"] = "Alan Smith";
message2.Label = "important";

var message3 = new BrokeredMessage("Third message");
message3.Properties["From"] = "Kelly Smith";
message3.Label = "information";

var client =  TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString(servicebusConnectionString, topicName);
 client.Send(message1);
 client.Send(message2);
 client.Send(message3);
```

Receiver Code

```
const string topicName = "rightangle";
const string subscriptionName = "AllMessages";
const string sub1Name = "Filtered1";
const string sub2Name = "Filtered2";

NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

if (!namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topicName, subscriptionName))
{
    namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicName, subscriptionName);
}
if (namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topicName, sub1Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting subscription {0}", sub1Name);
    namespaceManager.DeleteSubscription(topicName, sub1Name);
}
Console.WriteLine("Creating subscription {0}", sub1Name);
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicName, sub1Name, new SqlFilter("From LIKE '%Smith'"));

if (namespaceManager.SubscriptionExists(topicName, sub2Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting subscription {0}", sub2Name);
    namespaceManager.DeleteSubscription(topicName, sub2Name);
}
Console.WriteLine("Creating subscription {0}", sub2Name);
namespaceManager.CreateSubscription(topicName, sub2Name, new SqlFilter("sys.Label='important'"));

var options = new OnMessageOptions();

var subClient =                    SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName, subscriptionName);
subClient.OnMessage(m => MessageReceived(subscriptionName, m), options);

var subClient1 =                    SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName, sub1Name);

subClient1.OnMessage(m => MessageReceived(sub1Name, m), options);

var subClient2 =                    SubscriptionClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, topicName, sub2Name);

subClient2.OnMessage(m => MessageReceived(sub2Name, m), options);

private static void MessageReceived(string subscriptionName, BrokeredMessage message)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} '{1}' Label: '{2}' From: '{3}'", subscriptionName,
            message.GetBody<string>(),
            message.Label,
            message.Properties["From"]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. After running this example `AllMessages` contains three messages , `Filtered1` has two messages and `Filtered2`has one messages. Are you sure that there's no another instance of consuming code is running and retrieving those message?

`AllMessages` has a default SQL filter, so it's a "catch-all" subscription. Filtering would not affect it and it should get *any* message sent to `rightangle` topic. If you see no messages under it, either messages are consumed, or application is re-building entities and hence deleting all messages.

Try changing the receiver code not to delete entities, but only receive. And modify the sender to ensure entities exist and if not create those, but not remove. Alternatively, you could cobine the two (Receiver code first and then the sender) and you'll see the messages. Issue is solely with how entities are managed (deleted).

Comment: Thanks, your answer forced me to look a little more closely at my code.  My sample code did not include the fact that I added a try..catch..finally block and in the finally section I included a Console.Readline() method.  Apparently the **AllMessages** subscription would get processed immediately and then it would sit and wait at the Readline() until a key was pressed before processing the remainder of the code.  Removing the Readline() allowed the messages to be processed and filtered accordingly.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped you.